# CPH4 is exist or not

Tags: medical-science, biology, psychology, neurology, computers

what if our brain really works at more than 50%.In Lucy movie they were telling about the drug name CPH4 or they tell that it will produce at the time of pregnancy when women is at 5 or 6 months.Is this true a drug CPH4 really produce at the time of pregnancy if it is true then is it really helpful for increasing our brain power or not.

Comment: Also the "we use 10% of our brain" story has been disproved over and over again. See: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/59/do-we-only-use-10-of-our-brain ,  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4265/disproving-the-10-brain-myth-with-empirical-evidence and links within.

Comment: Are we seriously going to entertain questions that basically boil down to "Is the stuff they talk about in this science fiction movie real?" on this site rather than scifi.stackexchange.com ?